# Review counts not matching review queue?

Tags: bug

Ok, this is probably a "I'm a dumb new 10k user" type question (yes, she *did* nominate as a mod ;) ), but I keep getting notifications for there being items in the queue:

[image: Nine items in the queue]

However, when I check the queues, there is nothing there:

[image: Empty queues!]

I looked over at the Tools section but nothing jumped out at me.

I poked around meta.Workplace.SE for an answer, but I couldn't find a reason.  Is this a blonde moment, or is there something going on here?

Comment: Not a blonde moment; that number is often wrong.  I've seen discussion of it on Meta.SE but don't have a link handy.  The number in the header is a site-wide number, and cached.  With luck somebody will find the relevant MSE posts and write a proper answer.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Ok, thanks!  I did wonder if it were site-wide.  I saw go up to 13, I cleared a few which dropped it to 10.  A few minutes later it was 9 again when I hadn't been near the queues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will point to [Notify users of possible reviews on toolbar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/191638/213963) on MSE which is the feature that was requested and implemented (with some changes).

The number in the header reflects the total number of pending review tasks available.  Not all of them may be available to you - you may have already voted on some outside of the review queue.  You may have cast votes on the tasks before (and had the question been reopened) in which case you are ineligible for doing another review on the question. [Caching](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/).

[The change to the taskbar is massively annoying](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5762/the-change-to-the-taskbar-is-massively-annoying/5763#5763) explains a bit more about the number and how they are generated.

> However, unlike the numbers shown to you and everyone else in /review, this number counts everything - including tasks you aren't personally eligible to review. This includes tasks you've already done, tasks you've skipped, and tasks that the system expects you might not be sufficiently impartial to review (e.g., things you've already flagged or posted).

Comment: Thanks!  That just about covers it :)

Comment: If you poke at the 10k tools page (review -> tools -> close (last 30 days)), you can get a hint of what tasks are sitting around in that queue that might need some action.

Comment: Thanks again, I will do just that! :)